# How to properly implement RabbitMQ queue with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, rabbitmq, amqp

I need delivery changes from backend(Django) to Meteor. A do that through RabbitMQ, at Meteor's side I use amqp from npm. I send information about orders, sometimes order can change state to 'Close' and that means what I need just remove it from Meteor collection. But when load is increase sometimes 'close' action recived early then it's create and I have  discrepancy between backend and frontend.
Is it possiable to start amqp listener at one thread at the meteor side. Or how I can fight against this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here:

1. Don't instantly remove documents from the collection, but mark them as 'closed'. In this case client will subscibe only to unclosed documents. You can remove old & closed documents periodically, or after some some delay (i.e. by using Meteor.setTimeout)
2. On the meteor side, create a queue of 'close' actions that have no corresponding documents.  Then, when a new document is created, check the queue if it should be immediately closed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using [smart-collections](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-smart-collections) in your Meteor application, you could directly update your MongoDB Collection in your Python code, and have the changes propagate directly to your Meteor application, eliminating the need for a messaging queue.

I've read in a few places that Smart Collections are a lot faster than Meteor's Collection implementations because of it using the oplog. It's also going to be implemented in the core soon.

Comment: When you update Database directly, you have lost animation and updates goes from polling this is about 3 seconds.